# How to get value of <source src='...' using preg_match all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i am trying to get the value of src= using preg_match_all method but keep gettinbg this erro and my echo is empty! could any one help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

error:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

pointing at line:

```
echo "url:".$match[1][0];
```

php code:

```
$str="........<source  src='http://somewebsite.com/hls/playlist.m3u8?token=23452345463456243dsfasdasdfasdfdsfsdfa=='  type='video/mp4'  ></source>.......";
if(preg_match_all('/\<source  src=(.*?)\'/',$str,$match)) {     
        var_dump($match[1]);            
}
echo "url:".$match[1][0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two spaces, not one, also you should put the `'` after the `src`s `=` so you dont have that in expression.

```
$str="........<source  src='http://somewebsite.com/hls/playlist.m3u8?token=23452345463456243dsfasdasdfasdfdsfsdfa=='  type='video/mp4'  ></source>.......";
if(preg_match_all('/\<source\h+src=\'(.*?)\'/',$str,$match)) {      
        var_dump($match[1]);   
}
echo "url:".$match[1][0];;
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(87) "http://somewebsite.com/hls/playlist.m3u8?token=23452345463456243dsfasdasdfasdfdsfsdfa=="
}
url:http://somewebsite.com/hls/playlist.m3u8?token=23452345463456243dsfasdasdfasdfdsfsdfa==
```

You'd probably be better off using a parser for this though. For example if other attributes are before the `src` this won't work.

Comment: Thanks chris85 that fixed the problem! in the whole string there is only one "<source  src=" so it worked for me. By mentioning other attributes you mean other tags ?

Comment: No, like `width`, `height`, etc. Any other attribute. Also if double quotes are used this also won't work. Parsers are built to account for these things as well as spaces already. For example `<source height="400" src=` this would fail (I don't know if that is valid mark up, just a simple demo).